# Arabic text rendering issues in PDF using iText 7 and .NET

Tags: c#, .net, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

I am having trouble rendering Arabic text correctly in PDF files generated using the iText 7 library with the .NET programming language. Arabic letters appear separated from each other, and they are also reversed from left to right.

**The question:**

Are there any known solutions to this problem? Are there any specific steps I need to follow to ensure that Arabic text is rendered correctly in PDF files using iText 7 and .NET C#?

**This is an image that illustrates the problem after creating the document:**
[image]

**Additional information:**

```
Programming language: .NET c#
iText library: 8.0.3
```

**Source code:**

```
using iText.Kernel.Font;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Layout;
using iText.Layout.Element;
using iText.IO.Font;
using System;
using System.IO;
using iText.Layout.Properties;

namespace ArabicPdfExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var arabicFontPath = @"D:\Amiri\Amiri-Regular.ttf"; 
            string outputPath = "arabic_pdf_example.pdf";
            Document document = new Document(new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outputPath)));
            PdfFont bf = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(arabicFontPath, PdfEncodings.UTF8); 
           document.SetFont(bf);
            document.Add(new Paragraph("مرحبا بكم welcome 2024").SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT));
            document.Close();







            Console.WriteLine($"PDF generated successfully at: {Path.GetFullPath(outputPath)}");
        }
    }
}
```

**What I have tried:**

```
I have tried using different solutions such as changing the text direction and setting specific Arabic fonts.
I have also tried using other libraries such as PDFSharp and Spire.PDF, but the problem persists.
```

Comment: Are you using the iText [pdfCalligraph add-on](https://itextpdf.com/products/pdfcalligraph)?